# Where to create Swing Timer in class that extends applet

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, applet

I would like to use a Swing `Timer`, in a Java class that extends `Applet`, like the following:

```
timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        // change polygon data
        // ...

        repaint();
    }
});
```

I am using the timer to rotate different drawn polygons, when I click on the area where a polygon is drawn.

My question is where to insert the above code to create a timer? In the `init()` method or somewhere else?

Comment: BTW - why use `Applet` (as opposed to `JApplet`) in this millennium?

Comment: Well, because the university system in my country is all the way down. Besides being outdated, it burdens us with about 15 to 20 projects per semester, most of which should probably take one semester to complete.(not the case with this question, which I needed for a Lines game in Java Applet, that shouldn't take that long :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create the `Timer` in `init()`
- Start the `Timer` in `start()`
- Stop the `Timer` in `stop()`

Comment: I tried creating the timer in init() and then called timer.start() in paint()(when the mouse was clicked). Is that a wrong approach?

Comment: @biggdman: yes, that is wrong. You want to have no program logic in paint. If you want to initiate an action on mouse click, then put it in the MouseListener.